# Домен с 'www' и без

Tags: https, домен, сертификат

Почему домен с приставкой `www` считается другим? То есть `https` сертификаты нужно создавать отдельно для `test.com` и `www.test.com`. Как вообще называется эта приставка?

Comment: WWW? World Wide Web...

Comment: я знаю как расшифровывается, каково ее предназначение вначале урл?

Comment: Указать что это ссылка. Однако вместо `www` сейчас в основном `http://` или `https://`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляя www к домену, Вы получаете уже поддомен, а это может быть совершенно другой сайт, для совершенно других целей, организации и т.д. Просто исторически сложилось, что www означает именно сайт, но это правило уже давно не действует и остается на усмотрение администратора.
Например, у меня есть домен example.com. На него завязаны сайт, почта, чат, система учета и т.д.. Для удобства и интуитивного понимания можно сделать так: www.example.com - веб-сервер (сайт), mail.example.com - почта, chat.example.com - чат и тому подобное. А например shop.example.com я могу сдавать в аренду под интернет-магазин другому лицу и он будет использовать для него свой ssl сертификат, а на остальных поддоменах будет мой сертификат.
Поисковые системы тоже считают www.example.com и example.com совершенно разными сайтами, с разным контентом и рейтингом, поэтому для SEO эти домены надо склеивать, чтобы не было дублированного контента и санкций от ПС.

Answer (score 1):

www - это домен третьего уровня, это не специальный синоним, не приставка, а полноценный домен, наряду скажем с subsribe.test.com

- .com - домен первого уровня
- .test.com - домен второго уровня
- .www.test.com - домен третьего уровня